# Select section zoom rectangle without clicking (powerpoint)

Tags: powerpoint

On a slide I have three section zoom rectangles and want to automatically selection and click on a particular zoom rectangle upon presenting the slide.

How can I select section zoom rectangle without manually click?

Comment: I don't understand the negative vote. Nevertheless its bit of programming to get it done.

Comment: This is maybe because your question is not about programming but about general software, there is an array of sites in stack exchange that you can use for all kinds of issues see https://stackexchange.com/sites#, maybe [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/?newreg=9a6f4b2e1dbd475ba26199f41011a150) is the right one for this question.

Comment: @anastaciu Danke ;-) I may know there is no straight forward solution for emulating a mouse click on the slide and need a bit of scripting or programming to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Section Zoom**

A Section Zoom is a link to a section already in your presentation. You can use them to go back to sections you want to really emphasize, or to highlight how certain pieces of your presentation connect.

**Create a section Zoom**

**Go to Insert > Zoom.**

[image]

**Select Section Zoom.**

[image]

Select the section you want to use as a Section Zoom.

Select **Insert**. Your Section Zoom will be created.

**Tip:** If you want to, you can create a Section Zoom quickly by simply selecting the section name you want in the thumbnail pane and dragging it onto the slide you'd like to have a Section Zoom on.

Comment: There is only this way you can use this. Thanks

Comment: Yes. I have section zoom created on a slide. During presentation I want to select one of the section and continue without any mouse clicks or hovers

Comment: Is it possible to inject a macro and let it run.

Comment: Yes you can please refer to this article :- https://bettersolutions.com/powerpoint/macros/example.htm